# xCode - UIVisualEffectView animating

Tags: ios, xcode, animation, blur, uivisualeffectview

I've an issue while animating a VisualEffetView.
Here is the code where I declare it.

```
UIBlurEffect* blur = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleLight];
effectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blur];
effectView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
effectView.frame = self.bounds;
self.layer.borderWidth = 1;
[self addSubview:effectView];
```

When I animate the superview to make it grow, the Visual Effect follow the animation of the superview, but when I want to reduce it, the Visual Effect disappear instantly making the result very ugly ^^
Here is the code where I animate the superview (called recherche here)

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f
                          delay:0.0f
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone
                     animations:^{
                         CGRect f = recherche.frame;
                         f.size.height = 0;
                         [recherche setFrame:f];
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         [recherche removeFromSuperview];
                         recherche = nil;
                     }];
```

Here is what I have when I make recherche disappear. The white square seems to be the Effect View because the color changes if I change the UIBlurEffectStyle. But blurring effect is missing x)
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Question: Are you removing super view of a view in which effectView is added, Right?

Comment: That's what I do in the completion Block. But only the Blur View disappears. That's why I put a border line. I used it to see the view animations.

Comment: See even in animation you are setting its height to zero. So that does not make sense, zero height will not show superview. What you wanna achieve, do you have any screenshot or reference link or an example to add in question then please update it.

Comment: I want to hide the superview, then I make it disappear by setting its height to 0. And I want the Blur effect does the same thing. It works properly when I display the superview.

Answer (score 0):

From above understanding, I figure out that you just need to reset height of effect view to achieve what you want.

Added code in animation block:

Check and let me know, is it full fill your expectation.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f
                      delay:0.0f
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone
                 animations:^{
     CGRect f = recherche.frame;
     f.size.height = 0;
     [recherche setFrame:f];

     // Add this lines
     CGRect effectViewFrame = effectView.frame;
     effectView.size.height = 0;
     effectView.frame = effectViewFrame;

 }
 completion:^(BOOL finished){
     [recherche removeFromSuperview];
     recherche = nil;
 }];
```

Comment: Now I'm blank, You need to post a screen shot or gif animation to show issue.

Comment: I figure out what you want to achieve. Take a help from this git repo - https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXBlurView