# UIVisualEffectsView animation bug

Tags: ios, uiviewanimation, uiblureffect

I'm trying to animate a UIVisualEffectsView with a blur effect on top of a UIImageView. Animating the effects view 'in' seems to work, however when animating it 'out' on the first animation frame the effect vanishes to what looks like a 0.5 alpha view.

Is this a bug in iOS8 or am I doing it wrong?

You can play with the example project at https://github.com/mickeyl/iOS-Bug-Example-Projects/tree/master/Animating-UIVisualEffectsView

Here is a preview of what I'm seeing:

[image: Animating UIVisualEffectsView bug]

Update: Obviously the problem is the height parameter in the new rect. Keeping it works around it. If you then add the effect as subview to the image and clipToBounds, I can get the intended effect. Still I view this as a bug.

Comment: I can not say it is a bug, but yes many users have faced this kind of issue. Related thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27483860/xcode-uivisualeffectview-animating/27484424#27484424

Comment: Opened a rdar. Please do so as well and feel free to refer to my example project.

Comment: Good, I'll do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the response from Apple Developer Relations:

> This issue behaves as intended based on the following:
>
> When animating the height 0 -> 300, the presentation layer in the
>   render server knows its full size so the render server can properly
>   sample for blur. When returning back to zero height, the presentation
>   layer now has a height of zero, to which the render server has no way
>   to sample correctly. So the effect drops but the remaining layers
>   still animate properly.
>
> Your solution is the correct one. The render server simply cannot
>   accommodate blur in this scenario.
>
> Please update your bug report to let us know if this is still an issue
>   for you.